# How to count usage of items in mongodb with a single query?

Tags: mongodb, grouping, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have the following data:

```
{_id: 1, tags: ['foo', 'bar']}
{_id: 2, tags: ['bar',]}
{_id: 3, tags: ['foo',]}
{_id: 4, tags: ['bar', 'foo']}
{_id: 5, tags: ['foo']}
```

I would like a query to return the number of times each tag is used. In this case the tag "foo" was used 4 times and "bar" was used 3 times. I'm guessing the aggregate functions would help me here but not sure how. Please help me with an example!

Thanks gurus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out :)

```
db.test.aggregate({$unwind: "$tags"}, {$group: {_id: "$tags", total: { $sum: 1 }}});
```

I wouldn't mind if someone knew a more efficient way though :)